# Unable to create call adapter for in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, dagger-hilt, ktor

I'm trying to fetch list of Client in my App.
I made Ktor backend and put clients there. Im using Retrofit for fetching and Hilt for DI.

In my android app i made api:

```
@GET("/clients")
fun getAllClients(): List<Client>
```

In clientListRepoImpl:

```
override fun getAllClients(): List<Client> {
        return clientTrackerApi.getAllClients()
    }
```

In ViewModel I call interface clientRepository:

```
 init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val clients = clientsRepository.getAllClients() 
        }
    }
```

In listScreen:

```
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<ClientListViewModel>()
val myContext = LocalContext.current
LaunchedEffect(key1 = myContext) {
    viewModel.viewModelScope.launch {
        Log.d(TAG, "ClientsListScreen:")
    }
}
```

I also got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for
> java.util.List<android.tvz.hr.clienttracker.data.domain.model.Client

I checked that ktor is returning Client e.g. of 1 Client:

```
[

    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ronnie",
        "age": 23,
        "picture": "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A18",
        "aboutUser": "something"
    }

]
```

EDIT:

client model:

```
data class Client(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val picture: String? = null,
    val aboutUser: String? = null,
)
```

Im trying to fetch list of Client from my backend to show it in LazyList in Compose.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit further? Idk about other users but I am struggling to picture the context of your code fragments. For example, the configuration of your retrofit instance.

Comment: Im trying to fetch list of clients from my backend api. I made my own api in ktor. But when im trying to fetch list of clients i got this error. I divided code to MVVM so that is easier to read code. Hope i helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to make **getAllClients()** suspended function or return **Call<List<Client>>**. The second one will make your code look like this:

```
val call = clientsRepository.getAllClients()
call.enqueue(object: Callback<PlacesFoo>() {
      
      override fun onResponse(Call<List<Client>> call, 
                             Response<List<Client>>response) {
        
      }
      
      override fun onFailure(Call<List<Client>> call, Throwable t) {
        
      }
    })
```

Also use auto completion by android studio don't copy paste this, there could be a mistake.

Comment: I forgot suspend, thanks